# Numerical differentiation proof - Taylor polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following claim: Let $[a, b] ⊂ R $ and $x ∈ (a, b)$
be given. And E is the error of numerical differentation. If $f ∈ C^3 [a, b]$, then it holds that:

$| f'(x) - \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}| \leq max_{E \in [a,b]} \frac{|f'''(E)|}{3!} h^2$

As I see it: I have to show the left side is less or equal to the right side. LHS is differentiated one time, RHS differentiated 3 times. My guess is to use Taylor polynomial, is that right? And if, then how to apply as a proof?

Comment: "$E$ is the error of numerical differentation": nope.

Comment: No? Please elaborate?

Comment: Who told you so ?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$f $ is $ C^3([a,b],\Bbb R) $ .
By Taylor-Lagrange formula, and for very small $ h $,

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+\frac{h^3}{6}f'''(c_1)$$
and
$$f(x\color{red}{-h})=f(x)\color{red}{-h}f'(x)+....$$